# Quasi-Monte Carlo sampling with a summation constraint

Tags: summation, sampling, constraints, monte-carlo

**The problem**
Given arbitrary integers $n$ and $d$, I want to sample $n$ data points, each of dimension $d$. An additional constraint should be satisfied, namely that the values of each individual data point should sum to 1. I want the generated set to be of low-discrepancy (evenly spread in the space, with little gaps).

**My attempt**
Sampling low-discrepency sets is typically done by Quasi-Monte Carlo sampling, for example by means of the Halton sequence. For $n=16$ and $d=2$, a Halton sequence will produce the following:

[image]

One method would be to normalise each data point such that the constraint (each data point should sum to 1) is satisfied, but doing so will not leave the low-discrepancy property intact. This is shown below: the points are clearly not evenly spread across the diagonal line and there are gaps and clusters among them.

[image]

For $d=2$, the solution $\{\{\frac{0}{n}, \frac{n}{n}\}, \{\frac{1}{n}, \frac{n-1}{n}\}, ... , \{\frac{n}{n}, \frac{0}{n}\} \}$ should satisfy. But for $d \geq 3$, I am not sure what a good solution would be. I tried searching for literature that discusses this problem but was unable to find anything useful.

**The question**
What is an effective way to do low-discrepency sampling while maintaining this 'summation' constraint? Can anyone point me to some relevant literature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you doing the normalization in your picture? For the 2D example, have you considered just erasing the $y$-coordinate and setting it to $1 - x$? (In higher dimensions you wouldn't be able to repair all points by modifying the last coordinate, but it **might** work to just oversample the number of points you need and only retain the ones that are repairable; I'd need to think more about it.)

Comment: The normalization is done by dividing each value by the total sum, so $x_{new} = \frac{x}{x + y}$.  Your approach makes sense, thanks a lot. I'll have a go at it tomorrow and will provide an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing my comment out to an answer. I'm not **sure** that this will work, but I think it's worth trying.

Let $H_n^d$ denote the first $n$ points from the $d$-dimensional Halton sequence. Since you're really trying to generate points on a $(d-1)$-dimensional space, consider generating $x_n := H_n^{d-1}$, then setting the $d^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of each of the points in $x_n$ to be $ 1- \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} x_i$.

The catch is that in many cases, this last coordinate will be negative, which is undesirable -- but we can just discard the points in $x_n$ for which that holds and oversample points until we have the number of them we need. If you generate $d-1$ independent uniformly random numbers, the probability that their sum will be less than $1$ is $\frac{1}{(d-1)!}$, so that gives a good heuristic for how many we'd need to generate. The modified algorithm would look something like this:

- generate $x_n := H_{(d-1)! \cdot n}^{d-1}$ (you might need a few more terms than $(d-1)! \cdot n$ to account for the non-randomness of the Halton sequence)
- set the $d^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of each point in $x_n$ to be $1 - \sum_{i=1}^{d-1} x_i$
- discard the elements in $x_n$ for which the final coordinate is negative

Unless I'm underthinking something, it seems clear to me that if you take points generated in this way and project them down to the first $d-1$ coordinates, they'll have the desired distribution (sparsely covering the whole space). It would probably be wise to project them to other $(d-1)$-dimensional subspaces to be sure that they haven't clumped together in a way that's not obvious to me.

Comment: Seems to work fine! 'Montgomery Sampling' seems to outperform Normalised Uniform and Normalised Halton sampling in terms of discrepancy. I used a [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.qmc.discrepancy.html) function to compute discrepancy. I have uploaded some plots [here](https://imgur.com/a/j9OXoTn) for demonstration. Especially on the first plot you can see a nice triangle. Thanks!

Comment: This may work depending on the task. But I do not think it is mathematically correct. Oversampling and projecting will destroy the quasi Monte-Carlo properties. I think it is better (and more efficient!) to generate $n$ $d-1$ dimensional Halton points in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ and then map those into the desired subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ by a rigid motion. Only this will leave the relative distances of the $n$ points unchanged.

Comment: @gg What quasi MC properties will be destroyed? I'm not sure I follow your argument (though you certainly may be right). My concern with the rigid motion is how to do that in a way that preserves volume, which strikes me as both crucial and hard, since the target space has a different shape than the $d-1$-dimensional subspace. This tactic is definitely wasteful, though, I agree.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about this answer: note that it will distort distances some. For instance, if lifting the points $A = (0.2, 0.3), B = (0.3, 0.2), C = (0.3, 0.3)$ to the plane in 3D so that $A' = (0.2, 0.3, 0.5), B' = (0.3, 0.2, 0.5), C' = (0.3, 0.3, 0.4)$, note that the distance between $A$ and $B$ is preserved, but the $A/C$ and $B/C$ distances are increased. However, these changes are easy to bound, and the fundamental "non-closeness" of the points will be preserved; maybe that's enough for your application.

Comment: Yes indeed, my approach does not work. I was not aware that you wanted to fill the $d-1$ Simplex not the Cube in $S$. The natural conclusion would be to sample the triangle in d-1 but I fear QMC on non-rectangular domains is a topic of active research. See e.g. this [paper](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/students/KinjalBasuThesis.pdf)